# What's the best practice for storing encryption keys in a Java Tomcat web app for encrypting/decrypting sensitive data in a database?

Tags: java, spring, postgresql, tomcat, encryption

We have run into a requirement to encrypt certain sensitive data before storing it in a PostgreSQL database. Our application is a Spring app running on top of Tomcat. We need to store the keys so that our web app can encrypt data before inserting it and decrypt data after retrieving it.

We would like to avoid storing this type of thing in our config files (or files that are filtered by Maven) since those files are checked into source control and readable by anyone with access. We seem to have the same issue with database credentials but it looks like [JNDI datasources](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.0-doc/jndi-datasource-examples-howto.html) might solve those.

Are there best practices for this when using Tomcat? Things like environment variables might work but would be cumbersome to maintain.

EDIT: To clarify, we're trying to prevent sensitive data loss due to unauthorized access to the actual database file. Our db lives on a different physical box from our app server so we feel comfortable keeping the keys on the server that the application server lives on.

Comment: how jndi solves issue with database credentials?

Comment: Should it be encrypted so that any user with a key can see it, or encrypted per user?

Comment: From what I understand, JNDI allows you to set up the connection to the database (including host name and credentials) in the app server itself. Then from the app, all you do is use a JNDI name to look up/initialize the connection.

Comment: @ChrisWilliams Correct. So this means that with a JNDI data source, the DB credentials are sitting in a clear-text file on every app server. If any app server is compromised, your DB is compromised.

Answer (score 2):

As far as I have seen, all the best practices around credentials optimize ease-of-use (for the operations team) and code simplification (for the development team), rather than optimize for security. This is very disappointing.

I would state the requirement as: Do not ever store any credentials or encryption keys in an unencrypted form, whether embedded in properties/config files, source code, or files managed separately from the application.

Some effects of this requirement:

1. JNDI data sources do not work for DB credentials, because the configuration of the JNDI data source resides in a configuration file in the container.
2. Passwords/passphrases for encryption/decryption (e.g., for the data in a database) cannot reside in the code or a properties file.
3. You must implement a way for the operations team to pass the secrets to the application as it is instantiated.

How might you design a system to meet this requirement?

Store all of your secrets in an encrypted file in a centralized location (e.g., in Amazon S3 or a Hardware Security Module). The passphrase/credentials to read this encrypted data must never be stored digitally - it is provided (e.g., in the body of a POST) when the app spins up. In addition to the passphrase to the secrets file, you may also need to dynamically provide credentials to get access to the file itself.

When the application receives the passphrase to the secrets file, it cracks it open and initializes it's internals (e.g., create DB data sources, initialize the encryption services, etc.).

Answer (score 0):

You don't need encryption. You need access control.

Best practice? Yes. Cheap? No:

1. Don't use a single web server user account to log in to the db. This allows privilege escalation and data theft via SQL Injection. **Use a unique connection per user**. This kills connection pooling and allows maybe 500 simultaneous users max per db box.
2. Use a database that supports **Row Level Security** and Column Level Security. Right now, this is just Oracle. PG9.5 will have it. You can mimic it in 9.4
3. Put the db in its **own network zone**. Only the web server can connect.
4. Use a DAM (**database activity monitor**) to look for bad queries in and too much data out

A guide: https://securosis.com/assets/library/reports/Securosis_Understanding_DBEncryption.V_.1_.pdf

Comment: Hmm. Thanks for the answer. I don't think an HSM is an option for us due to cost and complexity. We're ok with not being able to search or sort based on the fields we need to encrypt. Our concern isn't authorized users getting to the data, it's unauthorized users getting to the physical data files.

Comment: @ChrisWilliams what exactly is the threat?

Comment: The threat is that the database server could be compromised. We'd like there to be an extra level of security around this sensitive data in case the database server itself is exposed.

Comment: @ChrisWilliams I assume you mean by an unknown external party, like a hacker